# Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Tags: swift

I need use a if-else statement to get different results like the code below, but got the error "Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types". How can I fix it?

```
struct drawObj: View {
    var ann: Annotation
    var body: some View {
        if ann.name == TYPE_RECTANGLE
        {
            return Rectangle().stroke(ann.color, lineWidth: ann.lineWidth!)
        }
        else
        {
            return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```